# Sort associative array by value descending

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array with keys as strings. Now I want to sort them by value descending.

This is the expected result:

```
[orange: 3, apple: 2,  banana: 1]
```

But with:

```
    var arr = [];
    arr["apple"] = 2;
    arr["orange"] = 3;
    arr["banana"] = 1;

    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.val - b.val;
    });
```

I get the initial order:

```
[apple: 2, orange: 3, banana: 1]
```

Comment: As Oriol said, you're treating the array as an object. With few exceptions, [everything in JavaScript acts like an object](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general), and using square bracket notation with strings instead of indices is just a way of defining named properties on an object. If you need to retrieve the values in an order based on their property names, you can play with the [`Object.keys` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), sort it and loop through it to access your values.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, the keys of an array should be non-negative integers.

If you use other keys, you are treating the array as a plain object, not as an array:

```
var arr = [];
arr.apple = 2;
arr.length; // 0 -- array methods will ignore your property
```

Since you are not using the special behavior of arrays, you should use a plain object instead:

```
var arr = {
  apple: 2,
  orange: 3,
  banana: 1
};
```

However, the properties of an object are not ordered. So sorting them makes no sense.

To bypass this restriction you could use an array of objects, e.g.

```
var arr = [
  {key: "apple", value: 2},
  {key: "orange", value: 3},
  {key: "banana", value: 1}
];
```

Then you will be able to sort these objects as explained in [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/1529630)

Comment: What kind of bracket is the right one in your 3rd example?

Comment: No, you used [ at the beginning, but } at the end of your 3rd example.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.